# Passing two form variables in a single URL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfform

I'm running the following form inside abc.cfm.

// Parameters Defined

```
     <cfparam name="startdate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-40,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
<cfparam name="enddate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-1,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">






     <cfform format="HTML" action="datedownload.cfm" method="get" >


    <cfformgroup type="horizontal">

      <cfinput type="dateField" name="startdate"  width="100" value="#startdate#">
      <cfinput type="dateField" name="enddate"  width="100" value="#enddate#">
      <cfinput name="submitApply" type="submit" value = "Apply">

        <cfinput type="button" name="download" value="Download" onclick="window.location.href='datedownload.cfm?startdate=#form.startdate#&enddate=#form.enddate#path=http://abc.xyz.com/username/July30/datedownload.cfm'"> 




        </cfformgroup>



        </cfform>
```

Everything is printing fine with the following code in datedownload.cfm

```
Startdate: <cfdump var = "#startdate#">
End Date :<cfdump var = "#enddate#">
```

Except that, the Enddate is printing full path along with it as follows:

```
Startdate: 2013-06-20 End Date : 2013-07-29path=http://abc.xyz.com/username/July30/datedownload.cfm
```

How can I remove the stuff starting from path?

Comment: Stop using cfform and cfinput. It offers no advantages over doing it the real way. Also...what didn't work? The link did not appear as you expected? there was an error going to download.cfm? Details....we need details.

Comment: @ScottStroz Thanks for your reply but nothing was displayed when I substituted your code inside the body section of my Download.cfm file.

Comment: That is because you are not outputting anything in download.cfm. As a test, add `<cfdump var="#form#" />` before the `</body>`, you should see the startdate and enddate values.

Comment: You are also building the query string wrong.  There should be a single "?" after the path to denote the start of the query string.  Then, the name value pairs should be delimited with a "$".  So you should have something like..  download.cfm?a=123&b=asdf

Comment: That should be a single "&" not "$".

Comment: You for got a & after `#form.enddate#` in your onclick handler, so everything after is being treated as part of enddate.

Comment: Using something like Startdate: <cfdump var = "#startdate#"> is a terrible idea.  You just made bad code worse by not scoping your vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, you are getting an error that startdate and enddate are not defined in the form scope when you try to load download.cfm. Since you are passing those variables to download.cfm as part of a query string (by submitting the form using GET), they would not be present in the form scope.

I can think of 2 quick and easy solutions:

First, you can change your reference to `form.startdate` and `form.enddate` to `url.formdate` and `url.enddate` respectively. Variables passed in as part of the query string (like when you do a GET) become part of the url scope, not the form scope (liek when you do a POST).

Second, you can param the variables like this in download.cfm:

```
<cfparam name="url.startdate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-40,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
<cfparam name="url.enddate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-1,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
<cfparam name="form.startdate" default="#url.startdate#">
<cfparam name="form.enddate" default="#url.enddate#">
```

This will first param the values in the url scope to the same values you have in the page that displays the form, then it will param the same variable names in the form scope to the same value of the same variable names in the URL scope.

Comment: Why do you want me to define the variables again in download.cfm ? I have already defined the cfparam variables in my file(for ex: abc.cfm) where I have created form.

Also, could you check my query string?

Comment: This it to make certain that if anyone hits download.cfm directly, it will not throw an error. paraming variables in one page, will not param them in another in a different request.  Dave Ferguson already told you how the query string should look.

Comment: I just updated my code and now I'm getting an unusual error saying that startdate is not defined in FORM.

Comment: I figured out that there is no need of `path=http://abc.xyz.com/username/July30/datedownload.cfm` in query string. I can get both the dates without it using cfdump.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as a correct answer if it worked for you.

Comment: One different problem I have started facing is associated with the Apply button. I believe since it's defined in the form, when I click on the Apply button, it's taking me to that Download page as well. I don't want it to take me to Download page when I'm using Apply button. Should I define two forms in my cfm file?

Comment: Change the action attribute of your form (and stop using cfform) from download.cfm to apply.cfm (or whatever page you are processing the form). Since you are using onclick to go to download.cfm, you need not specify that in the 'action' attribute. If my answer helped address the issue in the main question..please feel free to 'accept' it as an answer. :D

Comment: By the way what should I use if not cfform as I'm working on Coldfusion?

Comment: ummm...<form>. You need not use <cfform> simply because you are using ColdFusion. It will benefit you as an overall developer to NOT use cfform, or any UI stuff in ColdFusion...learn how to use these things the real way.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ampersand before *enddate* instead of the question mark and add an ampersand before the *path* variable

```
window.location.href='Download.cfm?startdate=#form.startdate#&enddate=#form.enddate#&path=http://abc.xyz.com/<username>/Testing/Testing/Download.cfm'
```

Comment: The above solution is not working. I'm still getting an error on the Download.cfm page when I'm trying to display startdate.

Comment: Minus 1 from me.  You are trying to access form variables without submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using a form post?  That's the way I prefer to do it.  I also test the request type (POST versus GET) to ensure that the download file isn't bookmarkable.

You'll need to use javascript to get the dates in the web-based form, not ColdFusion.  (The user will also need to have javascript enabled to use the form to use location.href.)

Give your form fields matching IDs and try the following:

```
window.location.href='Download.cfm?startdate='+ document.getElementById('startdate').value +'&enddate='+ document.getElementById('enddate').value +'&path=http://abc.xyz.com/<username>/Testing/Testing/Download.cfm';
```

I'd recommend not using CFForm tags since they require the the /CFIDE/ directory and is currently recommended to be blocked:

- [Secure CFIDE Directory for ColdFusion](https://kb.edgewebhosting.net/KnowledgebaseArticle53822.aspx)
- [ColdFusion 9 Server Lockdown Guide (PDF)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/91025512-cf9-lockdownguide-wp-ue.pdf)
- [ColdFusion 10 Server Lockdown Guide (PDF)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion-enterprise/pdf/cf10-lockdown-guide.pdf)

Make sure you perform date validation on the server-side.  If you need client-side date validation, you can use HTML5 DOCType and the attributes [type="date" & required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) or consider using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (preferable to CFForm validation).

Comment: I'm still getting an error after using your approach:

 Element STARTDATE is undefined in FORM.
 
The error occurred in C:\xyz.abc.com\<username>\Testing\Testing\Download.cfm: line 10
`
8 : <body>
9 : 
10 : <cfoutput> The Start Date you selected is: #form.startdate#</cfoutput>
11 : 
12 : <cfoutput> The End Date you selected is: #form.enddate#</cfoutput>`

Comment: FORM scoped variables are only available if you use a FORM "post", otherwise all URL parameters are in the URL scope (ie, URL.StartDate & URL.EndDate).

Regarding "validation on the server-side", this is recommended to protect against XXS (cross-site scripting) and SQL injection.  It is not so the user can verify the dates that the user just submitted.

`<cfparam name="URL.StartDate" type="date">`
`<cfparam name="URL.EndDate" type="date">`
`<cfif URL.StartDate GTE URL.EndDate>Invalid Date Range<cfabort></cfif>`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve your problem is to get rid of the 2nd button.  It is not necessary and will confuse not only you, but your users.  Since your form method is "get" the two formfields will be part of the url scope which seems to be what you want.

Also, where are the form variables coming from in the value attributes of your two inputs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.What do you mean by removing second button? I need two buttons 1) Apply and 2) Download. I have updated the code which explains from where the form variables are coming in the value attributes of two inputs.

Comment: Use radio buttons or a drop down to allow the user to decide what to do.